# Have multiple async code waiting for the same task to finish in Swift

Tags: swift, async-await, swift-concurrency

I have a generic request async method that I use to make all the network requests of my app.

The first thing this method does it to check if the access token is still valid, and if it's not, the token is refreshed. However, this `accessTokenRefreshableService` can only be called once because the refreshToken it uses is only valid once.

In order to ensure `accessTokenRefreshableService` is only executed once, and that all the `request` wait until the `accessTokenRefreshableService` has finished I have added a `semaphore.wait()` and `semaphore.signal()`. But it does feel like a wrong solution, plus using it gives the following warning:

*Instance method 'wait' is unavailable from asynchronous contexts; Await a Task handle instead; this is an error in Swift 6*

What would be the proper way to get this behavior?

```
func request<T: Decodable, S: APIServiceProtocol>(service: S) async throws -> T {
    // Access token
    semaphore.wait()
    if let accessToken = service.accessToken {
        if JWT.isTokenExpired(accessToken) {
            try await accessTokenRefreshableService.request()
        }
    }
    semaphore.signal()
    
    // Prepare request
    // Make request
    // Handle result
}
```

Comment: Why are you using semaphores? Can you explain more clearly what "proper executions" you are trying to ensure?

Comment: @Sweeper, I have edited the question, I hope I made it more clear

Comment: Okay, so many callers are going to call this `request(service:)` function, but you only want `accessTokenRefreshableService.request()` to be called once per expiration. Did I understand correctly? Sounds like the `if` statement you showed could be extracted into its own method, isolated to an `actor`.

Comment: Does `accessTokenRefreshableService.request()` change `service.accessToken` in some way? The former doesn't seem like it is related to `service` at all, but from your description, it seems to make `JWT.isTokenExpired(accessToken)` false?

Comment: @Sweeper, yes, this is precisely what I'm trying to do. Could you elaborate on this isolated `actor` solution?

Comment: Yes, `service.accessToken` is actually a computed property that gets the accessToken from UserDefaults, and `accessTokenRefreshableService.request()` updates this when the result is success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would redesign this as an actor that always give you a valid access token.

```
actor AccessTokenSource {
    private var accessToken = "Some Invalid Token" // perhaps read this from UserDefalts
    
    var refreshTask: Task<String, Error>?
    
    func get() async throws -> String {
        if let refreshTask {
            return try await refreshTask.value
        }
        if JWT.isTokenExpired(accessToken) {
            let task = Task {
                // request should be changed to return the new token
                return try await accessTokenRefreshableService.request()
            }
            refreshTask = task
            let newToken = try await task.value
            accessToken = newToken
        }
        return accessToken
    }

    // if you really want to use user defaults
    func updateUserDefaults() async throws {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(try await get(), forKey: ...)
    }
}
```

If the token has expired, the actor requests a new one, and importantly, sets the `refreshTask`. This indicates that a new token is being requested. If another call to `get` finds a non-nil `refreshTask`, it waits for the result of that task, instead of requesting a new one.

Make sure you only have one instance of this `AccessTokenSource`.

```
let accessTokens = AccessTokenSource()
```

Now you just need to call this in `request(service:)`

```
func request<T: Decodable, S: APIServiceProtocol>(service: S) async throws -> T {
    var token = try await accessTokens.get()
    // or try await accessTokens.updateUserDefaults()

    // the rest of the things that this function should do...
}
```

Minimal Example:

```
actor AccessTokenSource {
    private var token = "Foo"
    
    var refreshTask: Task<String, Error>?
    
    func get() async throws -> String {
        if let refreshTask {
            return try await refreshTask.value
        }
        if !token.hasPrefix("Bar") { // let's suppose this means the token is expired
            refreshTask = Task {
                // simulating getting the new token...
                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))

                // give a random number to the new token
                return "Bar\(Int.random(in: 0..<10000))"
            }
            let newToken = try await refreshTask!.value
            token = newToken
        }
        return token
    }
    
}

let accessTokens = AccessTokenSource()

func request() async throws {
    let x = try await accessTokens.get()
    print(x) // this prints the same token for all the calls, meaning that only one request is sent
}

for _ in 0..<100 {
    Task {
        try await request()
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds exactly what I need, but I just implemented this code and it's not doing this. Calls to `refreshTokenIfNeeded` are still being done in parallel. I have used exactly the same code you suggested here (just remeved the `T: Decodable` to make it compile)

Comment: I'm preparing a minimal reproducible example, I will update the question with it in a few minutes

Comment: I have edited the answer with a minimal example using Actors. Please let me know if i'm missing something obvious

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper, I manage to get this working. I still store the accessToken somewhere else and I only use this actor to store the refreshTask and ensure it is only run one at a time.

Comment: This is not a good solution for the problem, since an access token is an opaque data type for the client. That is, on the client side there is no function like "isTokenExpired". Only the server knows that. Also, the information whether a token is expired is immediately stale after getting it, that is, even when it is not expired on the client side, it may be expired when used on the server side. So, this technique is inherently flawed.